# Is PAC file compiled or interpreted?

Tags: javascript, proxy, pac

Suppose I have two exceptions in the PAC file as follows:

```
if (shExpMatch("host",abc.xyz.com))
{
return "PROXY 165.225.123.124:80";
}

/*
.
.
.
*/
if (shExpMatch("host",*.xyz.com))
{
return "DIRECT";
}
```

Now as per the first exception in the PAC file, if I access abc.xyz.com, then it should go to PROXY, but as per the second exception which is written after the first exception, anything containing xyz.com should go Directly to the internet.

So which rule should be applied to the request abc.xyz.com?

If the PAC file is interpreted from top to bottom then I think the request should go to Proxy but if the PAC file is compiled and then evaluated, then it should go directly?

Comment: Even compiled code does run sequentially.